# Need to comapre two CSV files using powershell scripts

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Am having 2 CSV files

Actual. Csv file contains installed  software name and version available in computer..retrieved through powershell script and save it as CSV file

For eg:
Actual.csv

```
Name     Version
Cisco    11.9
Chrome   10.5
Fireeye  12.3
```

I created other csv file name Expected. Csv with monthly upgraded software name and version

Expected.csv

```
Name       Version
Chrome     10.5
Fireeye    12.4
```

So I need to compare my Expected csv file with actual csv and need to show If any difference found in Expected sheet.

So for my above example I need answer like

```
Name      version
Fireeye   12.4     mismatchwithactual
```

Comment: have you tried `Get-Help compare` yet?

Comment: have you tried to search for it? [Powershell + compare + csv + file](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[Powershell]+compare+csv+file)

Comment: Hi I searched lot but not able to find exact one